# What is the call depth limit in Sitecore PowerShell and can it be overridden?

Tags: powershell-extensions

I have a recursive script that hits a `System.Management.Automation.ScriptCallDepthException` exception.

What is the call depth limit in Sitecore PowerShell and can it be overridden?

Note: Yes, I can probably refactor to avoid recursion.

EDIT: For a little clarity, it's a script to copy items from one site to another, maintaining "localized" links based on the two sites having parallel structures. The outline looks like this in pseudocode:

```
Queue1 = System.Collections.Generic.Queue<Sitecore.Item>
Queue2 = System.Collections.Generic.Queue<Sitecore.Item>

Function HandleQueues()
    If Queue1 > 0
        ProcessQueue1
        HandleQueues
    Else If Queue2 > 0
        ProcessQueue2
        HandleQueues
    End if
Return

Function ProcessQueue1()
    Do while Queue1 > 0
        Pop Top item
        Do stuff with it
        Add it to Queue2
    Loop
Return

Function ProcessQueue2()
    Pop Top item
    Do stuff with it
    Find if it has links to anything that needs to go into Queue1 and add them
Return
```

Obviously there's plenty of scope for *possible* infinite loops, but I've handled pretty much all I can think of, and going through the script output I can't see any repetition. I'm pretty sure the code is logically sound, if a little brutal with building a call stack, so the question remains a technical one.

Comment: I think that you've got a recursion that cannot find an exit point. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't think so, and I don't see any repetition in the script output. It runs fine for a small amount of items. The recursive function handles two queues - each of which can add items to the other, but I've closed the possible infinite loop between them.

Comment: And you're certain, adding items to either queue does not reset the enumerator?

Comment: Yes. The recursive function doesn't enumerate - just checks queue A and queue B to see if they have items in, then calls functions to process the queues (the first is enumerated, the second pops one item). After checking which queue to process it calls itself. If both queues are empty it exits. It works perfectly on small sets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two points to consider.

### Call Depth Limit

Windows Powershell may have a [call depth limit of 100](https://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/working-around-a-powershell-call-depth-disaster-with-trampolines). Consider changing your code to use <s>tail-recursion</s> trampolines as pointed out in the article instead.

Not this kind of trampoline:

[image: imgur]

This kind of trampoline:

```
$stack = New-Object System.Collections.Stack

#Load first level
Get-ChildItem -Path "master:" -ID "{0DE95AE4-41AB-4D01-9EB0-67441B7C2450}" | ForEach-Object { $stack.Push($_) }

Write-Host "Beginning processing of stack."
while($stack.Length -and ($item = $stack.Pop())) {
    Write-Host "Processing item $($item.ID) - $($item.Name)"
    Get-ChildItem -Path "master:" -ID $item.ID | ForEach-Object { $stack.Push($_) }
}

Write-Host "Completed processing stack."
```

[image: Results]

### Recurse Depth for Get-ChildItem

In version 4.7 of SPE (came out sooner) you can set the depth limit while calling `Get-ChildItem`.

```powershell
Get-ChildItem -Path "master:\content\home" -Recurse -Depth 1
```

[image: Screenshot]

**Note:** Updated statement above regarding tail recursion based on the comment below and the fact the linked article says to...I must not have read it properly the first time.

Comment: That's useful, but it's not in a Get-Item call, unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, but `Get-Item` does not perform a recursive call either. Perhaps you can update the question with a sample script to help clarify what script is revealing the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I maent Get-ChildItem, not Get-Item. But yes, I'll try and provide a bit more meat on the bones of the question. It's certainly not an issue with any commands or such, and I'm 99% sure I don't have an infinite loop. It's purely my code structure hitting a limit.

Comment: I've fixed my code now, but just to note that PowerShell doesn't support tail recursion optimisation (this would allow simply moving the recursive call to the last line of the function). I used a very simple trampoline pattern outlined in the linked article: The once-was-recursive function now returns true if it wants to be called again, and a simple do while loop calls it until it returns false.

Comment: Nice update! Hoping for Microsoft to launch Marsupial View Controller pattern soon.